# Can't get values from form?

Tags: javascript, php

I can't get the value from the form. Due to Firebug the form is submitted tho and when I delete the js it works so it has something to do with it.

```
$ok= $_POST['ok']; //this doesnt work

if($ok== "ok" ){ 
  echo "works";
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var frm = $('#form');
        frm.submit(function (ev) {
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),

            });
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
    });

 function submitForm2() {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
</script>

<div onclick='submitForm2();'></div>

<form action='' method='post' id='form'>
        <input type="hidden" name='ok' value="ok">

    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Due to Firebug the form is submitted"? How does Firebug cause the form to be submitted?

Answer (score 1):

When the form is submitted, your first set of JavaScript kicks in. It:

- Stops the normal submission process running
- Takes the data from the form and submits it via Ajax

Since the normal form submission doesn't run, the page doesn't reload, so you don't load a new document, so you don't see the document with the *ok* in it loaded in the main browser window.

Since you don't have a `success` handler for the Ajax request, you **completely ignore** the response the server sends back to the JavaScript … so you don't see that document (with the *ok* in it) either.

**If you want to see the results of an Ajax request, then you have to write JS to show you the results** (or examine the Net tab of your developer tools).